# Instantiating trait objects causes compiler warning in rust: trait objects without an explicit `dyn` are deprecated

Tags: rust, traits

I get these warnings appearing that will soon become errors but I cannot for the life of me figure out what I need to do with the type expression to eliminate these.

```
warning: trait objects without an explicit `dyn` are deprecated
  --> src/main.rs:62:46
   |
62 |     let module_store: Arc<dyn ModuleStore> = ModuleStore::new(&write_rs);
   |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^ help: use `dyn`: `<dyn ModuleStore>`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(bare_trait_objects)]` on by default
   = warning: this is accepted in the current edition (Rust 2018) but is a hard error in Rust 2021!
   = note: for more information, see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/edition-guide/rust-2021/warnings-promoted-to-error.html>
```

I have a few of these errors.
You can see the source code there. I can annotate the types but it doesn't make a lick of difference. This has been hanging over me for a while without a solution and I've spent time researching - I'm hoping someone can help me identify my error here.

```
let module_store: Arc<dyn ModuleStore> = ModuleStore::new(&write_rs);
let module_store = ModuleStore::new(&write_rs);
```

I can annotate it, it doesn't matter. Do I need a turbofish or something? It's unclear to me.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Including declarations for `ModuleStore` and `write_rs`.

Comment: Try `Arc::new(ModuleStore::new(&write_rs));` and see if the issue is gone.

Comment: How is `new` defined?

Comment: Did you try to apply the compiler suggestion in `help` message? If yes, what didn't work as expected?

Comment: Does `write_rs` implement `ModuleStore`? I'm guessing yes, or you should have gotten an error about "type annotation needed". If so, one of those should work: `write_rs.new()` or `(write_rs as &dyn ModuleStore).new()` or `<dyn ModuleStore>::new (&write_rs)`.

Comment: `let write_rs = RedisStore::new_writable(conf.clone()).unwrap();`
is a struct that only implements itself + Clone.

new is defined like so for the ModuleStore:
`pub fn new(redis_store: &RedisStore) -> Arc<dyn ModuleStore> {
        Arc::new(redis_store.clone())
    }`

Comment: Jmb's last example is what works. Sorry - I couldn't figure out how to parse that compiler warning...

Answer (score 0):

Jmb gets this one -
The answer is to call new w/ dyn like so:
`let module_store: Arc<dyn ModuleStore> = <dyn ModuleStore>::new(&write_rs);`